# Reemplazar valores NaN por una cadena

Tags: python, replace

He probado con fillna() y para reemplazarlos por ceros si me ha servido pero no se como reemplazarlo por un texto. Por ejemplo para cambiar los NaN por 'None'

```
inmuebles.garage_cond.fillna('None')

inmuebles[inmuebles['garage_cond'].isna()]
```

Pero siguen los NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que está ocurriendo es que realmente no estás modificando dicho objeto. Tienes dos opciones (realmente seguro que hay más, son las que se me han ocurrido:

1. `inmuebles.garage_cond = inmuebles.garage_cond.fillna('None')`
2. `inmuebles.garage_cond.fillna('None', inplace = True)`

En esta segunda, el argumento `inplace = True` es el que hace que la función modifique el objeto.

Comment: Te dejo aquí la [documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) de la función ```fillna```